# Is there a way when Migrating a Room Database to use Variables that are calculated during the Migration?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-room

I'm writing an Android App in Java and I've changed my Database and now I want to migrate it to the new version but to do that I need to compute some of the old values and then insert those into one of the new tables into the db but when I call

```
database.execSQL()
```

with my variables and then access them it appears to not have set them as every value is 0.

Is it just not possible or did I simply miss something?

```
public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
             database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE 'season' ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                    'spring' INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 'summer' INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 'autumn' INTEGER 
                    DEFAULT 0, 'winter' 
                    INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 'spook' INTEGER DEFAULT 0)");
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO 'Clothes' (type_of_clothing,clothing_name,description,seasonId,in_laundry,TypeList) " +
                    "SELECT type_of_clothing,clothing_name,description,type_of_clothing,in_laundry,TypeList " +
                    "FROM ClothesNew");
            Cursor cursor = database.query("SELECT * FROM Clothes");
            Cursor secondCursor = database.query("SELECT * FROM ClothesSeason");
            ArrayList<Season> seasonsToBeAdded = new ArrayList<>();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                secondCursor.moveToNext();
                int Sid = cursor.getInt(0);
                String seasonString = secondCursor.getString(2);
                Season season = new Season(seasonString);
                int tempId = Sid;
                boolean isInList = false;
                for (Season tempSeason : seasonsToBeAdded) {
                    if (tempSeason.equals(season)) {
                        tempId = seasonsToBeAdded.indexOf(tempSeason);
                        isInList = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isInList) {
                    season.setId(seasonsToBeAdded.size());
                    tempId = season.getId();
                    seasonsToBeAdded.add(season);
                }
                if (seasonsToBeAdded.size() == 0) {seasonsToBeAdded.add(season);}
                
                database.execSQL("UPDATE Clothes SET seasonId = :tempId WHERE uid = :Sid");
            }

            int id, spring, summer, autumn, winter, spook;

            for (Season season : seasonsToBeAdded) {
                id = season.getId();
                spring = season.getSpring();
                summer = season.getSummer();
                autumn = season.getAutumn();
                winter = season.getWinter();
                spook = season.getSpook();
                database.execSQL("INSERT INTO season " +
                        "VALUES(:id, :spring, :summer, :autumn, :winter, :spook) ");
            }
            Cursor otherCursor = database.query("SELECT * FROM season");
            ArrayList<Integer> springValues= new ArrayList<>();
            while (otherCursor.moveToNext()) {
                springValues.add(otherCursor.getInt(1));
            }
        }
```

When I look at the Values stored in springValues they are all 0 even though I add the correct ones in this query

```
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO season " +
                 "VALUES(:id, :spring, :summer, :autumn, :winter, :spook) ");
```

Can I just not use the :var notation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest utilising The `SQLiteDatabase` [`Insert`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) convenience method along with a `ContentValues` object.

Instead of :-

```
        for (Season season : seasonsToBeAdded) {
            id = season.getId();
            spring = season.getSpring();
            summer = season.getSummer();
            autumn = season.getAutumn();
            winter = season.getWinter();
            spook = season.getSpook();
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO season " +
                    "VALUES(:id, :spring, :summer, :autumn, :winter, :spook) ");
        }
```

Your code could then be :-

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); // Instantiate ContentValues object
    for (Season season : seasonsToBeAdded) {
        cv.clear();
        cv.put("`id`",season.getId());
        cv.put("`spring`",season.getSpring());
        cv.put("`summer`",season.getSummer());
        cv.put("`autumn`",season.getAutumn());
        cv.put("`winter`",season.getWinter());
        cv.put("`spook`",season.getSpook());
        database.insert("season",null,cv); //<<<< Recommended Uses the convenience Insert Method
```

- Note there should be no need to enclose the column names in grave accents `` as used above.
- The above code is in-principle code and has not been tested, as such it may contain some errors.

As you can see the SQL is built for you. The `insert` method returns the rowid (id column) of the inserted row or -1 if the insert failed, you may wish to take advantage of this value.

You may also wish to utilise other insert methods e.g. [insertWithOnConflict](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) e.g. `database.insertWithOnConflict("season",null,cv,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);`

It would also be advisable to utilise transactions by utilising the appropriate SQLiteDatabase transaction handling methods (see [beginTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#beginTransaction()))

It also also recommended that you utilise constants for column names so the name is coded in just on place. So little chance of getting the column names wrong.